# Error restoring a sql server database on mac using a docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-data-studio

I am trying to restore a backup to a docker container that contains the sql server 2019 service.
I am using Mac and for which I am using Azure Data Studio for the connection

**Script in Azure Data Studio**

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 
  N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/FuelControlAndHourMeter-202244-8-37-54.bak'
```

**Result**

> BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/FuelControlAndHourMeter-202244-8-37-54.bak' failed to open. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Comment: But does the user/group `mssql` have access to that path? I would suggest it does not. What are the permissions and owners of `/var/opt/mssql/backup/`?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 501 dialout 62 Apr  4  2022 FuelControlAndHourMeter-202244-8-37-54.bak -> /var/opt/mssql/data/FuelControlAndHourMeter-202244-8-37-54.bak
@Larnu

Comment: Those are _your_ rights, can the `mssql` user see the same? How did you create `/var/opt/mssql/backup/`? Can you show the results of `docker exec -it 075990 ls -l /var/opt/mssql/backup/`?